# Reading the output streams from a C/C++ coded application

Tags: c++, c, io, stream

First of all, i'm on Ubuntu 14.04

So, here's my problem: I'm dealing with a C++ coded application that has a graphical interface (games/music players/etc). This application constantly sends strings to a logger whenever something happens, but those are only visible inside the client.

What I've tried to do already (failures):

- strace the application and filter the results (let's say if the application showed the message "Hello, user", i would log all the outputs to a test file and search for "Hello")
- ltrace the application
- debug the application with dbg
- search for debug methods on C/C++ apps

What I've got from this last method is that programs usually log errors and messages through a `clog` stream. What could I do to retrieve that information?

Resuming, I have a graphical C/C++ coded application that constant inputs strings on a window inside the client; I want to read those strings or any other strings/inputs this application does. Any debugging/memory reading information may also be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: If it sends these messages to the standard error stream you could redirect that stream to a file by starting the program from terminal like so `program-execution-instruction 2> your-file.txt`

Comment: @aakashjain You mean strace this system call to a test file?

Comment: you could use freopen

Answer (score 0):

1. `std::cout` corresponds to *`stdout`* stream;
   `std::cerr` and `std::clog` corresponds to *`stderr`* stream.
2. By default, content "sent" to *`stdout`* and *`stderr`* is displayed in terminal.
   To see it, simply open terminal emulator (or, alternatively, terminal), type path where the program is and confirm using Enter. You're going to see content sent to `stdout` and `stderr`.
3. *`stdout`* is represented by number `1`, *`stderr`* by `2`.
4. Next hints are designed to work in `bash` shell. (they may work on another shells, but they don't have to). If you're not sure you're using `bash`, type `bash` in terminal and confirm using Enter.
5. When you want to send stream's content to file, after path (but before pressing Enter) write space and `n>filename`, where `n` is number of stream you want redirect (when skipped, `1`=*`stdout`* is going to be redirected). By default you won't see redirected content in terminal.
6. When you want simply completely ignore stream's content, redirect stream to `/dev/null`.
7. When you want send *`stdout`* to another program (if second program is console program, it's going to see it like entered by user using keyboard), after path (but before pressing Enter) type `|program_name and_possible_parameters`. You can in example redirect *`stdout`* to `grep`.
   `grep` is going to write only lines containing string passed as argument (after `grep`, type space and a string, if it contain a space, delimit argument using `""` or `''`, if it contain `'` `"` or `\` precede it with backslash (`\`). If it's result is going to appear in terminal, I recommend to write `--color=auto` between `grep` and argument to tell `grep` to write every occurrence of argument using different color.
   Finally, your command can look like
   `path_to_your_program |grep --color=auto "argument"`.
8. You can use more than one redirection in single command.
   Redirections are processed from left to right.
9. When you want to redirect *`stderr`* to input of another program, you can redirect it's content to *`stdout`* by typing `2>&1` and then use `|`.